# JMeter: Issue with cookie parametrization / extracting a AJAX-generated token

Tags: regex, apache, cookies, jmeter, csrf

This is kind of two questions around the same issue, so let me give some background on the issue itself first.  The questions I ask in the "Method" sections.

Background on the issue: I am using Apache Jmeter to load test a web application, and I created the test scripts using Jmeter's HTTP Test Script Recorder. During login to the application, a CSRF-token is generated through what looks like an AJAX script. It looks like the CSRF-token needs to be passed as a cookie in the HTTP requests that occur later in the test.

### I am having trouble capturing the CSRF-token through the following methods:

Method #1: Regular Expression Extractor

I've configured my regular expression extractor to grab the token from the HTTP response where the token is generated.  I've validated this by grabbing other cookies that are generated at this same HTTP request step, and I'm able to grab them successfully. However, for some reason I can't grab the CSRF-token in the same way.  As stated before, the application being tested seems to be generating the CSRF-token via an AJAX script. For some reason, I believe Jmeter cannot capture the token for this reason. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Method #2: Parameterizing Cookies using the Cookie Manager

Since using regex didn't seem to work, I was playing around with parameterizing the cookie manager as per the [official documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager). So, I've added ${COOKIE_X-CSRF-TOKEN} into the "Value" field of each of the "X-CSRF-TOKEN" headers being passed in the respective HTTP requests, for some reason it's not able to capture the token. I've added "CookieManager.save.cookies=true" to the jmeter.properties file as well.  Is there anything else I need to do configure the parameterization of cookies using the cookie manager?

Here's an example set of cookies that I see in the response of the respective HTTP request where the token is generated:

```
JSESSIONID: B3E98A6BB702BCDD460B99U97B1E6507
newuser:
nbbu_sid: 2F951797h299631_0000SID
X-CSRF-TOKEN: qliTGwGcAVhvYk8+VfyK3n3PmgpXS8f1Va8FSD8SuZE=
```

As stated previously, I am able to capture all other cookie values from this HTTP response message, but not the X-CSRF-token value. (Which I think is related to the AJAX script that is generating the token, but I'm not sure).

If not, then the issue might be the same as method #1's, where the way the token is being generated is the problem. :(

Any thoughts or guidance on the above would be very much appreciated.  I've seen some other questions posted that are somewhat related, but I felt that the answers to those questions would not be able to solve my problem.

Comment: You can make this question easier to answer by [edit]ing it to include an example cookie.

Comment: Thanks dorukayhan, I've added an example cookie set that I'm seeing in the HTTP response.  I'm able to capture all other cookie values using regex, but not CSRF for some mysterious reason.  My hunch is something  about the way the AJAX script generates the token is the issue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: would you please share the regular expression used to capture the token and screen shot of the test plan (only required parts, that shows HTTP request and regular expression extractors that you kept)? Also, confirm whether you used multiple groups (single regular expression extractor) or multiple regular expression extractors to capture both Cookies and Token?

Comment: THere's no general problem with cookies and AJAX requests in JMeter. Must be something specific. Are you sure it's a cookie? I.e. can you share the response that contains a "set-cookie" header with that particular cookie?